# Sorting through an array of names in a specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot and I have an array list of characters organized alphabetically. What I'm trying to do is make it so that when someone uses the command `$info (name)` the bot will look through the array with a for loop and grab the first name from the array that matches the chunk closest to the beginning of the string. 
So for example:

```
let namelist = ['adam', 'al', 'albert', 'bertie', 'cole'];

$info a 
/*would grab Adam because he's the first on the list alphabetically
with an 'A' in his name*/

$info ber 
/*would grab bertie because he's the first on the list with a ber in the 
beginning of his name, 
and not grab albert who has a ber later in his name and
is ahead of bertie in the array*/
```

This is what I have so far. Right now if I tried to do `$info ber` it would grab Albert because it runs into his name on the array first.
I thought about using substring and charAt but i couldn't find an efficient way of doing that. I was also thinking of using findIndex or indexOf but couldn't figure how to make that work with this.

```
for(let i = 0; i < namelist.length; i++){
 if(namelist[i].includes(name)){
 object = namelist[i];
 console.log(object);
 break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with [`startswith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to grab the first matching item from a sorted list:

```js
let namelist = ['adam', 'al', 'albert', 'bertie', 'cole'];

let s = "ber"
let found = namelist.find(item => item.startsWith(s))

console.log(found)

s = 'a'
found = namelist.find(item => item.startsWith(s))

console.log(found)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.find()` with `Array.startsWith()` to get names which start with a string. Since users might use upper case letters when searching, use `String.toLowerCase()` on the search string.

```js
const namelist = ['adam', 'al', 'albert', 'bertie', 'cole'];

const getName = str => namelist.find(s => s.startsWith(str.toLowerCase()));

console.log(getName('a')); // admin
console.log(getName('ber')) // bertie
console.log(getName('Ber')) // bertie
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

this ended up being my final code, ty ori and mark

```
            let words = args[0];
            let object = "";
            let temparray = [];
            let found = namearray.find(item => {item.startsWith(args[0])});
                    for(let i = 0; i <= namearray.length; i++){ 
                        if(i < namearray.length && namearray[i].startsWith(words)){
                            object = namearray[i];
                            console.log(object);
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(i < namearray.length && namearray[i].includes(words)){
                            temparray.push(namearray[i]);
                            console.log(temparray);
                        }
                        else if(i >= namearray.length && found === undefined){
                            console.log(temparray[0]);
                            object = temparray[0];
                        }               
                    }
```